# Save in view when rotate screen

Tags: android, layout

my layout is very heavy, so when you turn the screen takes a long time. How can I save my view "onSaveInstanceState" ??

My code:

```
if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {
            /*
             * ----------------- TAB DATA -----------------
             */
            try {

                System.gc();
                // initialize the class that needs to load the Activity
                myLayout = new TableMainLayout(this);
                // I tried to give some time to load, but that's not good!
                synchronized (this) {
                    wait(5000);
                }

                setContentView(myLayout);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("link", "Errore actionBarTabs update  Series: " + e);
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I understood when you change the orientation app does not want to read the data back, well put this code in manifest file in your activity that you do not want to read again.

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

This code allows you to freeze your activity.

For example:

```
<activity
  android:name=".MainActivity"

  android:configChanges="orientation"

  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >
</activity>
```